# Network drives not mapping correctly with group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, network-share

One of my clients is having random issues with the mapping of network drives.

Users get mapped drives from group policy based on the security groups they are in.

An example issue with one user:

- User was added to incorrect security group "Alpha", therefore was mapped the corresponding "Alpha" network drive.
- User was removed from group "Alpha", and added to group "Beta".
- gpupdate /force, restarted User's PC.
- User is still getting the "Alpha" drive, but not the "Beta" drive.
- gpresult /r indicates that the "Alpha" GPO is being applied (Applied Group Policy Object), and that the user is in the "Beta" security group and not the "Alpha" group.

Can someone please help?

Client PC - Windows 7 Pro x64

Server - Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Assuming you're using GPP, do you have **Remove this item when it is no longer applied** enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the user was in an OU "Alpha", so I moved them to OU "Beta".

The user then got the required "Beta" network drive.

I wasn't aware that users were split into OU's.